# How to retrieve layout orientation from Zend_Locale?

Tags: php, zend-framework, locale

I know that there is a LDML entry in Zend_Locale_Data for layout orientation based on locale:

```
<layout>
    <orientation characters="right-to-left"/>
</layout>
```

But I don't know how to retrieve it. I tried this:

```
Zend_Locale::getTranslationList('layout');
```

In returned array I couldn't find this information. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The orientation information is in the `characters` and `lines` entries in the returned array. If those entries are empty, then Zend_Locale doesn't have any information about that 
locale's orientation, meaning it's "normal" (characters left-to-right, lines top-to-bottom).

For example, calling getTranslationList for Arabic:

```
Zend_Locale::getTranslationList('layout', 'ar');
```

returns an array with `characters` set to `'right-to-left'`, and `lines` blank.

On the other hand, the same call with a locale of 'mn_Mong_CN' returns an array with `characters` set to `'top-to-bottom'` and `lines` set to `'left-to-right'`.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Try using `Zend_Locale_Data::getList('en_US', 'layout')` using your locale of course.

Updated to `getList`. I am not really all that familiar. Just trying to help.

Comment: Exception thrown. Layout is not defined as a key in this function.